# Examples of streams in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

can you give me few specific cases when using "streams" in Java 8 would be the best solution?

I did a lot of research on the internet but I couldn't find any specific cases...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you possibly searched with [query](https://www.google.com/#q=java+8+stream+api+example) on Google? There are quite a number of examples on the first result page!

Answer (score 2):

Many examples are provided in [*java.util.stream*'s package summary](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).
RTFM. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Currently we all are moving towards BIG DATA and Real Time no wonder if Java also starts thinking in that aspect. Java 8 Streams would empower the entire working model of Java Collections. Streams would help us processing huge amount of data (may be something like infinitely running streams) in parallel.
I have been blogging a Series of article on Java 8 Streams API. Please do visit for more information [amitph.com > Introduction to Java 8 Streams API](http://java.amitph.com/search/label/streams)